# Function Template Overloading with Different Return Types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, function-templates-overloading

Following code snippets are from [Function template overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading).

How is it possible to overload functions/function templates with return type `A<I+J>` vs `A<I-J>`?

Did the page really mean that `overload #1` & `overload #2` compose valid function overload set?

Or, have I misunderstood the meaning of the page?

```cpp
template<int I, int J>
A<I+J> f(A<I>, A<J>); // overload #1
 
template<int K, int L>
A<K+L> f(A<K>, A<L>); // same as #1
 
template<int I, int J>
A<I-J> f(A<I>, A<J>); // overload #2
```

I have tried the following in https://godbolt.org, which did not compile as expected with errors:

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:48:24: error: call of overloaded 'func<1, 2>(A<1>, A<2>)' is ambiguous
   48 |     A<-1> a = func<1,2>(A<1>{}, A<2>{});
      |               ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:35:8: note: candidate: 'A<(I + J)> func(A<I>, A<J>) [with int I = 1; int J = 2]'
   35 | A<I+J> func(A<I>, A<J>) {
      |        ^~~~
<source>:41:8: note: candidate: 'A<(I - J)> func(A<I>, A<J>) [with int I = 1; int J = 2]'
   41 | A<I-J> func(A<I>, A<J>) {
      |        ^~~~
```

```cpp
template <int>
struct A {
};

template <int I, int J>
A<I+J> func(A<I>, A<J>) {
    std::cout << "func1\n";
    return A<I+J>{};
}

template <int I, int J>
A<I-J> func(A<I>, A<J>) {
    std::cout << "func2\n";
    return A<I-J>{};
}

int main()
{
    A<-1> a = func<1,2>(A<1>{}, A<2>{});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like that example is meant to show that templates with equivalent template parameters and function parameters can be different declarations based solely on their return types. This is most commonly used where the return type is `enable_if_t<...>`

Comment: Being able to declare an overload set of functions and/or function templates is a distinct matter from being able to differentiate them in a call (or potentially any other way). In particular overload resolution for a function call expression does not consider the return type at all and so you can't differentiate the overloads with a function call expression. Still, they are distinct templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Templates which differ by return types only can still have a well-formed overload resolution if you cast the function explicitly when using in the client code. This is the only known to me way to disambiguate such templates, however, so the application is quite narrow and inconvenient:

```cpp
template<int I>
struct A {};

template<int I, int J>
A<I+J> f(A<I>, A<J>) {
    std::cout << "Overload 1" << std::endl;
    return A<I+J>{};
}

template<int I, int J>
A<I-J> f(A<I>, A<J>) {
    std::cout << "Overload 2" << std::endl;
    return A<I-J>{};
}

int main() {
    // well-formed
    auto a = static_cast<A<-1>(&)(A<1>, A<2>)>(f)(A<1>{}, A<2>{});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for everyone's information. With the help of reading all the comments, answers and some more testing, I am trying to give a consolidated answer for future reference.

To start with, I totally agree with [user17732522](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17732522/user17732522) that we should look at this problem from 2 aspects.

1. Non-template function/function template declaration:

   For non-template function declaration, return type is not taken into account.
   That's why following declarations will cause compilation error of `ambiguating new declaration of int func()`

   ```
   void func();

   int func();
   ```

   However, for function template declaration, return type is taken into account and that feature is useful as being pointed out by [artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754656/artyer) for SFINAE on the return type where `enable_if_t<...>` is used.
2. Non-template function/function template calling:

   As per [The Dreams Wind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5690248/the-dreams-wind)'s explantions,in case we would like to pick a specific definition of function template to call from an overload set, we either have to cast it to the specific type manually or by leveraging SFINAE as mentioned above.

   ```
   template <int>
   struct A {
   };

   template <int I, int J>
   A<I+J> func(A<I>, A<J>) {
       std::cout << "func1\n";
       return A<I+J>{};
   }

   template <int I, int J>
   A<I-J> func(A<I>, A<J>) {
       std::cout << "func2\n";
       return A<I-J>{};
   }

   int main()
   {
       A<-1> a = static_cast<A<-1>(&)(A<1>, A<2>)>(func)(A<1>{}, A<2>{});
       A<3> b = static_cast<A<3>(&)(A<1>, A<2>)>(func)(A<1>{}, A<2>{});
       return 0;
   }
   ```